# Converting lowercase letters to capitals

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie in Haskell and have some problem of defining a function that would convert all small letters to capital and leave the rest intact.

I tried solving this question in my book so far:

```
capitalise :: String -> String
capitalise xs = [capitalise2 ch| ch<-xs]

capitalise2 :: Char -> Char
capitalise2 ch 
    | isLower ch    = chr (ord ch - 32)
    | otherwise    = ch
```

I am getting errors:

```
p3.hs:6:7: Not in scope: `isLower'
p3.hs:6:23: Not in scope: `chr'
p3.hs:6:28: Not in scope: `ord'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that this sort of strategy will not work in certain languages, because some characters actually become more/less characters when making uppercase/lowercase.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, you need to `import Data.Char` to use those functions it is complaining about.

Right, you are missing the `otherwise` case in the new function.  Try it with an `if .. then .. else` construct.  Experienced Haskellers do not use that construct very much; I would probably do it with a helper function:

```
capitalize cs = [ toUpper c | c <- cs ]
    where
    toUpper ...
```

which is pretty much the same as what you already have, the main difference being the scope of the helper function.

See also [Data.Char.toUpper](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Char.html#v%3AtoUpper).

This may also be a good opportunity to break free of list comprehensions and start to play with higher order functions.  Try writing this function with [map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#g:11) instead of a list comprehension.

Answer (score 7):

Has the book explained the standard library yet?

```
import Data.Char (toUpper)

capitalise  =  map toUpper
```

Comment: @iPC better `import Data.Char`. If you're using the haskell98 module `Char`, you cannot use any modules from `base` with newer GHCs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `isLower` part of the expression, instead of using it as a filter.

```
[if isLower ch then chr (ord ch - 32) else ch | ch <- xs]
```

Or, move the helper function inside.

```
capitalise = map capitalise'
             where capitalise' ch
                      | isLower ch = chr (ord ch - 32)
                      | otherwise  = ch
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I won't be needing use another function right? or do I?

Comment: Using `chr`, `ord`, and `-32` is not the right way of doing this.  Use `toUpper`.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It gives the right result for ASCII, but it's not very descriptive.  You should use the proper tool for the job.